# Spring Query with optional nulls and case insensitive

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Boot 2.2.5.RELEASE with Java 8 and PostgreSQL and I need to retrieve some data from a table. To do that I can receive some optional values and they need to be case sensitive (mostly because some of them are Hex Strings). To handle that I'm using a CRUD repository with a query like the example bellow:

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository<MyStuff, String> {

    @Query("SELECT s FROM Stuff s WHERE (:name is null or upper(s.name) = upper(:name)) "
            + "and (:age is null or upper(s.age) = upper(:age)) "
            + "and (:status is null or upper(s.status) = upper(:status))")
    List<MyStuff> findStuff(@Param("name") String name,
                            @Param("age") String age,
                            @Param("status") String status);
```

I've removed some information to make it clear, but the gist of it is there. The problem is, only one field must have a value, the others can be null. It should be simple enough, because I'm checking for null before casting the fields to upper case, but when I try to run it I get an error because the null values are being interpreted as `bytea` and so there is no method to change its case.
How can I handle it without having a method in java to check for nulls and change to upper case on Java side?

Comment: using postgresql ? I reported a similar problem long time ago at https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13155 , not sure if it is fixed or not now ,but you can refer to the suggestion mentioned in that thread . I remember i finally construct the JPQL dynamically to solve the problem..

Comment: Yes. Sorry, forgot to mention that. Also, I may have stumbled in that issue. I was looking around and it seems like Hibernate casts "?" To `bytea` when receives a null value.

Comment: Run into this issue sometime ago; I remember searching a lot for this without much success. this works out of the box with h2 for instance; but not for postgresql. this behavior is related with how hibernate dialect for postgresql is implemented I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend that you do that. A DBMS will use a pretty conservative query plan when encountering something like that. You should use Spring-Data Specifications for conditional filters like this.

Comment: Do you mean something like Criteria Builder?

Comment: Here is an article about that topic: https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/